# How to get filesize of file generated using XMLStreamWriter?

Tags: java, stax

I am using XMLStreamWriter class from StAX to generate XML file from a java program. I followed [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/stax-xmlstreamwriter.html) and the XMLFile is getting generated correctly. How do I get the size of the file that has been generated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method [File#length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length--)

> Returns:
>   The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist. Some operating systems may return 0L for pathnames denoting system-dependent entities such as devices or pipes.

```
File out = new File("data\\output2.xml");
System.out.printf("file size: %d bytes%n", out.length());
```

With java 1.7 you can use the static method [Files#size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#size-java.nio.file.Path-) (note: File**s**)

```
Path path = Paths.get("data\\output2.xml");
System.out.printf("file size: %d bytes%n", Files.size(path));
```

Comment: The file has already been generated ? Wont your solution try to create a new file ?

Comment: @JayakrishnanGK No, the first one just creates a file Object, not the file on the file system (your HDD) for accessing information about the file. The second one creates a Path object, it is more specific for informations about paths.